# Downloaded pdf file using curl - issue

Tags: php, pdf, curl, zend-pdf

This is my curl code:

```
$fp = fopen('path/to/file/'. $id . '.pdf', 'w+');

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'myurl');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, '');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);

curl_exec($curl);
```

I managed to download my file. I can open it , but not in Chrome. Plus, if I am trying to open it with `$pdf = new Zend_Pdf(file_get_contents($pdfFile));` I am receiving the following error: `File is not a PDF`

I believe the way how I am saving under a specific name and put it on a specific folder, is not correct. Any way, ideas how to approach this ?

Thank you

Comment: It is upload script. Can you show how you handle that upload in `myurl`?

Comment: Hey @Justinas do you want the url ? from where I download the pdf ?

Comment: What/how are you opening the file? What do you mean by `not in Chrome`? I would try setting `CURLOPT_HEADER` to zero since adding headers to a PDF will very likely corrupt it.

Comment: @Dave ,yes it should be zero. If you add the answer, i will be happy to accept it :) thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are trying to retrieve "structured" files such as a PDF you do not want the headers returned too as they will usually corrupt the file being retrieved. Change

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
```

to

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
```